# Solve linear system with 9 equations and 9 uknowns using Gauss-elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having difficulties doing this exercise.

$$-4T_1+T_2+T_4=-100$$
$$T_1-4T_2+T_3+T_5=-20$$
$$T_2-4T_3+T_6=-20$$
$$T_1-4T_4+T_5+T_7=-80$$
$$T_2+T_4-4T_5+T_6+T_8=0$$
$$T_3+T_5-4T_6+T_9=0$$
$$T_4-4T_7+T_8=-260$$
$$T_5+T_7-4T_8+T_9=-180$$
$$T_6+T_8-4T_9=-180$$

Any help is highly appreciated. It needs to be done using the Gaussian method, and im a little bit rusty and dont see the obvious/best way to go.

Sorry bout late upload of system. Was formatting the post.

Comment: where is your System?

Comment: Which exercise? Anyway, with nine variables, I suggest getting a very large sheet of paper.

Comment: I think the best way to go is to start using "the Gaussian method."  Have you tried that?  It might work.

Comment: If you know how to solve a $3\times 3$ or $4\times 4$ system you should know how to do it on any dimension, it's just the same thin gover and over again.

Comment: @JonasVilla: Set up the $9 \times 10$ augmented matrix and RREF = $$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{390}{7} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{605}{14} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{190}{7} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{1115}{14} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 70 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{635}{14} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{790}{7} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dfrac{1565}{14} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dfrac{590}{7} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Have you learned the Cramer's rule? You can compute the value of $\,T_i, i=1,...,9$ directly by using it.

I think you can write the system into a $9$x$10$ matrix and try some row or column transformations to make it close to ($I_9$,b), where $I_9$ is the $9$x$9$ identity matrix and b is a $9$x$1$ column vector.

I want to write all these as a comment of this problem, but my reputation is not enough to do that. So I write it as a answer. But it is just my thinking.

Hope my words can help you.

Comment: Yea heard of the rule, but not yet. The exercise says to use the Gaussian elimination method.

Comment: have you a solution now?

Comment: Yes i have gotten the solution, and i have used the Gaussian method to retrieve the matrix "Moo" posted. But use so many steps, wanted to see if it can be simplified.. Since im also typing my results down in a Latex file, i want to shorten it down

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**.-Your (equivalent) matrix equation is 
$$\begin{equation}\begin{bmatrix}
-4&1&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\[1em]1&-4&1&0&1&0&0&0&0
\\[1em]0&1&-4&0&0&1&0&0&0
\\[1em]1&0&0&-4&1&0&1&0&0\\[1em]0&1&0&1&-4&1&0&1&0\\[1em]0&0&1&0&1&-4&0&0&1\\[1em]0&0&0&1&0&0&-4&1&0\\[1em]0&0&0&0&1&0&1&-4&1\\[1em]0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&-4    \end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix} T_1 \\[1em] T_2 \\[1em]T_3 \\[1em] T_4\\[1em] T_5 \\[1em] T_6\\[1em] T_7 \\[1em] T_8\\[1em] T_9\\   \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} -100 \\[1em] -20 \\[1em] -20 \\[1em] -80\\[1em] 0 \\[1em] 0\\[1em] -260 \\[1em] -180\\[1em] -180 \\   \end{bmatrix}\end{equation}$$
From this, your job using Gauss-elimination will be facilitated.

NOTE.- *It could be that there are some lapses in the numbers written down. I think not, but maybe yes.*